# SQL Server Group By with Max on Date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope i can explain the issue i'm having and hopefully so can point me in the same direction.

I'm trying to do a group by (Email Address) on a subset of data, then i'm using a `max()` on a date field but because of different values in other fields its bring back more rows then require.

I would just like to return the max record per email address and return the fields that are on the same row that are on the max record.

Not sure how i can write this query?

Comment: Can you please provide examples of your data and show what you want in result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select *
from
 ( 
   select t.*,
      -- assign sequential number starting with 1 for the maximum date 
      row_number() over (partiton by email_address order by datecol desc) as rn
   from tab
 ) as dt
where rn = 1 -- only return the latest row
```

Comment: Perfect !! That's working for me, just running this against my data now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this query using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emailaddress order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
select a.*
from baseTable as a
inner join
(select Email,
       Max(EmailDate) as EmailDate
from baseTable
group by Email) as b
on a.Email = b.Email
and a.EmailDate = b.EmailDate
```

Comment: 794353 test@gmail.com Explicit Opt Out 2011-09-17
622775 test@gmail.com Implicit Opt In 2015-03-23
1678362 test@gmail.com Explicit Opt In 2015-09-24